# DateTime Object get time regardless of the time zone

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have this string "2014-10-20T10:46:00+01:00", but cant figure it out how to display only "10:46". I use this, but it gives me "12:46":

```
dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Clearly it is relevant how you converted that string to "dateTime".  You need to post that code too.  And mention your time zone.

Comment: Posted it. My timezone is Bulgaria/Sofia.

Answer (score 2):

Since this string has [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) part, you might need to consider parse it to `DateTimeOffset` not `DateTime`. Then you can use [`.DateTime` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

One solution can be demonstrated in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "2014-10-20T10:46:00+01:00";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(s);
dto.DateTime.ToString("HH:mm").Dump(); // 10:46
```

Of course this string format should supported by your current culture in [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How is LinqPad relevant here?

Comment: @MattJohnson I just demonstared this code on LINQPad. As you can see I used `Dump()` extension method that's why I want to mentioned it.

Comment: Sure.  Just seems extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToLocalTime()` method instead of `ToUniversal()` of the `DateTime` type

**Edit**

What about using just `dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");`? It should give you what you need...

I have prepared some code to check it for you:

Test class looks like that:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization is done this way.

```
var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));

using (XmlWriter x = new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    s.Serialize(x, new Test { DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2014-10-20T10:46:00+01:00") });
}
using (var r = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
   var o = (Test)s.Deserialize(r);
   var result = o.DateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
}
```

The `result` is '11:46' as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I parse an XML into a DateTime property. My xml arrives as follows "2014-10-20T10:46:00+01:00", but I need to display 11:46. It displays 12:46. Why is that? Here is my prop:

```
private DateTime dateTimeField;

...

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public System.DateTime dateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((dateTimeField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.dateTimeField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("dateTime");
            }
        }
    }
```